# More Advanced Audio Controls in Java

Tags: java, audio

I need more control over playing sounds than `java.applet.AudioClip` provides. All that gives is the ability to play, loop-play, and stop an audio clip. I would like to know how to control on which speaker it plays, what the volume of the sound is, what part of the sound to play, etc. Does anyone have any experience or advice they would like to share?

### EDIT:

---

I have implemented `javax.sound`. The following is a VERY dumbed-down version of my code:

```
public class Clazz extends JFrame
{
  public java.net.URL alertSoundURL = getClass().getResource("/resources/beep.wav");
  javax.sound.sampled.Clip timeUp;

  public Clazz()
  {
    try
    {
      javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream audioIn = javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(alertSoundURL);
      timeUp = javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getClip();
      timeUp.open(audioIn);
      timeUp.setLoopPoints(0, 10000);
      timeUp.start();
      timeUp.stop();
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
      //Tell user sound may not work
    }
  }

  private void setOffAlarm()
  {
    alarmDialog.setSize(alarmDialog.getPreferredSize());
    FrameAction.center(alarmDialog);
    alarmDialog.setVisible(true);
    timeUp.loop(timeUp.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    newDay = false;
  }
}
```

my problem is that timeUp.loop(timeUp.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); only plays it once. Can someone solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the JavaSound API (classes in the javax.sound.* packages). Google will give you several tutorials on how to use them.

Comment: I tried that, but the Clip.loop(int count); command doesn't work; it only loops once.

Answer (score 0):

I have to support jarnbjo answer, however the documentation is not really good. The approach I found to play the same sound more than once is something like this:

First read it into a byte buffer named "data":

```
byte[] data;
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename); //in an applet
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
data = new byte[(int)ais.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize()];
byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
for (int i=0; i<data.length; i+=BUFSIZE) {
    int r = ais.read(buf, 0, BUFSIZE);
    if (i+r >= data.length) {
        r = data.length - i;
    }
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, data, i, r);
}
ais.close();
```

And then play the sound from that buffer named "data" (as many times as you like):

```
line.start();
for (int i=0; i<data.length; i+=BUFSIZE) {
    line.write(data, i, BUFSIZE);
}
line.drain();
line.stop();
```

This is actually taken from this forum: http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/16458-playing-audioinputstream-multiple-times.html. I didn't test it, but it looks good to me. See how far you get with this.